# How to reconnect automatically StompJmsConnectionFactory factory in ActiveMQ

Tags: java, apache, activemq-classic

Writing subscriber to Listen AMQ queues.Its working but i want to reconnect automatically whenever AMQ gets re-started or goes down. For this purpose added the code below:-

```
 StompJmsConnectionFactory factory = new StompJmsConnectionFactory();

            factory.setBrokerURI("failover:tcp://" + host + ":" + port+"?retryInterval=2000&reconnectAttempts=1000");

            connection = factory.createConnection(user, password);
```

But these setting is not working as expected ,To reproduce the scenario,I stopped the AMQ while subscriber is running and I debugged the program and see that it after crossing the above line of code it comes to catch block (Connection refused).

Not seeing any reconnect attempt has been made. Any Idea? where I am wrong. T removed the failover also I tried but same result

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are using the StompJMS client which as far as I know is not maintained at all any more so I'm not sure it's the best choice to start a development project with.

Since you are using Java why not just use the native Java JMS client for ActiveMQ which uses the OpenWire protocol and provides a broader set of features and much better support than the STOMP client?